# Deserializing Json VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am trying to deserialize data from a webserver for a game launcher.
The [API docs](https://github.com/ToontownRewritten/api-doc/blob/master/login.md) provide me the data in json format, but I have been struggling to be able to read that data I am given and store it as a variable to use to log in a player. I have also tried a few other things but I am just stuck now. 
Normally a response from the server would like like this:

```
{"success":"true","gameserver":"gameserver-alpha.toontownrewritten.com","cookie":"deadbeefdeafbeef0x123"}
```

The code to deserialize the data:

```
Dim result() As TTRServerResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TTRServerResponse())(responseFromServer)
```

Class with the variables I want to store

```
Public Class TTRServerResponse
    Public Property success As String
    Public Property eta As String
    Public Property position As String
    Public Property queueToken As String
    Public Property cookie As String
End Class
```

Any ideas where I messed up or what I should do? Thanks, Ben.

**EDIT**: Finally figured it out, I needed to change my result to: 
`Dim result As TTRServerResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TTRServerResponse)    (responseFromServer)` 
 I also was returning the data incorrectly to my other sub by returning just `result`. What I needed to do was return `result.success`. I now have a better understanding.

Comment: Have you tried setting your class to `Serializable`? According to the one above it's missing... Add this to the top of your class `<Serializable> _`...

Comment: You did not describe a problem or ask a question

Comment: Are you getting multiple json objects back or just a single one? Because in the example above, the sample json string won't deserialize since it's a single object, and you're trying to deserialize it into an array of objects. Your class structure must match the json structure _exactly_

Comment: Your type `TTRServerResponse` is missing a property `Public Property gameserver As String`.  Try uploading your JSON to http://jsonutils.com/, it can auto-generate a VB.NET class for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize the JSON into an array but in your example it is a single object.

So assuming

```
Dim responseFromServer As String
```

is equal to

```
{"success":"true","gameserver":"gameserver-alpha.toontownrewritten.com","cookie":"deadbeefdeafbeef0x123"}
```

Which, according to the documentation you linked to, is suppose to be a single object,

then you need to update your code to deserialize a single object as appose to an array

```
Dim result As TTRServerResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TTRServerResponse)(responseFromServer)
```